# Oracle SQL Developer using an always "true" conditional with delete from clause. ("xxx" is null or "xxx" is not null)

Tags: oracle, null, conditional-statements, oracle-sqldeveloper

I was using today Oracle SQL Developer version 19.2.1.247 and removed couple of rows using the graphical way. I mean, I selected the row and press the red x cross to remove the selected rows.
It worked, all fine. Rows were removed.

However, I took a look to the logs and find out this:

```
DELETE FROM "DB"."PERSONS" WHERE ROWID = 'AADG' AND ORA_ROWSCN = '5196' and ( "ID" is null or "ID" is not null )
```

Well, I don't understand the last statement.

```
"ID" is null or "ID" is not null
```

To my eyes, apparently, this is always going to be true. I feel curiosity about knowing the reason why this Oracle SQL Developer is adding this. Why is this used? When this statement will not be true?

Comment: It is never not going to be true and there is no apparent need to add it. As to "Why" you would need to as the designers for SQL Developer (unless there is any online documentation that documents "why" but that is unlikely).

Comment: Do you mean is never going to be false? Anyway, so there isn't a good reason to follow that approach? I just feel curiosity, maybe there's a good reason after it. So if there's, I can learn it.

Comment: "It is never going to be false" and "It is never not going to be true" are identical statements when you only have binary true/false options; so I meant what I said (and was trying to emphasise the always truthy-ness with the double-negative) but your statement is also valid.

Comment: Well, in SQL a `where` clause returns only rows with the `true` value of predicate, while it may evaluate to `true`, `false` or `unknown/NULL` (depending on the DBMS). So `not true` in terms of filtering condition in SQL is more accurate

Answer (score 0):

Probably just an anomaly, but it wont have any impact on the execution (or performance) of the statement. For example, I did:

```
SQL> create table t as select * from scott.emp;

Table created.
```

and then deleted a row in SQL Dev, yielding

```
DELETE FROM "T" WHERE ROWID = 'AAZRaiABAAAA5eLAAL' 
AND ORA_ROWSCN = '16330866545209' 
and ( "EMPNO" is null or "EMPNO" is not null )
```

and the optimizer came up with this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | DELETE STATEMENT            |      |     1 |    12 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  DELETE                     | T    |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY USER ROWID| T    |     1 |    12 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter("ORA_ROWSCN"=16330866545209)
```

The redundant predicates were simply ignored.

My table had no indexes or primary keys, so it would appear the simply takes the first column from the table for this predicate.